# Unity desktop in Ubuntu 16.04 overrides fonts.conf hinting config

Tags: unity, fonts

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus) with the default (unity) desktop environment. My problem is that my ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf is being overridden by the unity-tweak-tool, for example if I set something like:

```
<match target="font">
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
        <const>hintfull</const>
    </edit>
</match>
```

The system will still respect the "hintslight" setting from unity-tweak-tool. This is extremely annoying, as it doesn't allow any kind of deeper customization of the font settings. Additioanlly, autohint true/false makes no visual difference whatsoever. The only option that seems to be actually respected is antialiasing.

Any idea how to disable any configuration mechanism other than fonts.conf?

Thank you.